Conversion of Dictionary<TKey, T1> to Dictionary<TKey, T2> where T2 is a variable
Is there a way in C# to convert a dictionary into another dictionary if target key type is not changed and target value type is stored in a variable (as "System.Type") and conversion of each individual element is valid?
I tried a solution that used System.Reflection to get target dictionary type, then used activator to create a dictionary and then converted each individual element. The problem is that I need to cast the object created by activator into dictionary (otherwise I can't add elements into it) but it either requires value type (which I can't specify because it is a variable) or causes compilation error
